# Appengine send mail - mail not sending

Tags: python-2.7, email, google-app-engine

I am trying to sent email from my app once a form has been submitted.

I have used this import in my main.py

```
from google.appengine.api import mail
```

This is my request handler

```
#handle form data
#construct Consult
consult.put()
sender_address = "no-reply@*******.com.au"
mail.send_mail(sender=sender_address,
  to="jwc-testadmin@******.com.au",
  subject="***** - New Consult",
  body="""Dear JW Consultant, test.""")
self.redirect('/consults')
```

When I click submit the mail doesnt send. The Consult put() and redirect work fine.

Comment: are there any errors in the logs?

Comment: I actually get no error. I just realised I should mention this is testing locally with dev_appserver.py. Perhaps it will work when running in Cloud?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are running on the dev server the following information is pertinent:

> [The local development server can send email for calls to the App
>   Engine mail service using either an SMTP server or a local
>   installation of Sendmail.](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-local-server#using_mail)

Have you installed Sendmail or are you using a SMTP server?

Comment: I ran live on Appengine and it worked!! :) So my code was fine. Thanks for info re dev server needing a local mail server. I will set that up.

Comment: I'd recommend using one of the third party mail sending systems e.g. mailgun or sendgrid. Appengine mail is limited to 10 per day so not that useful for much...